# Link C++ program output with Python script

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig, boost-python

I have a C++ program that uses some very specific method to calculate pairwise distances for a data set (30,000 elements). The output file would be 20 GB, and look something like this:

```
point1, point2, distancex
pointi, pointj, distancexx
.....
```

I then input the file to Python and use Python (NumPy) for clustering. It takes forever using Python to read the output file. Is there a way to connect the C++ program directly with my Python code to save time on I/O on the intermediate file? Maybe using SWIG?

Comment: You might use a pipeline: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have been saving ascii. You could modify your C++ code to write binary instead, and read it with [numpy.fromfile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html).

For a more direct connection, you would wrap your C++ code as a library (remove main() and drive it from Python) using swig. This allows you to share the memory of arrays between C++ and Python.

You can use either Python's [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html)  on the C++ side together with [numpy.frombuffer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) on the Python side. Or you can use the [numpy headers](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html) to directly work on numpy arrays in C++. Here is a small [swig example project](https://github.com/martinxyz/python/tree/master/realistic) using the second method. (Disclaimer: I wrote it.)